# Why doesn't my css file properly link to my html file?

Tags: html, css

So I've been creating a project on my localhost server for the first time using wamp (I've only coded html/css/js in repl.it before this) and for some reason, my css will not
**stay** on my page. When I try changing styles using my CSS file, it shows up when I refresh, but then very quickly disappears. The following pictures represent this (NOTE: I had to record and slow down the refresh just to see that it did change):

[this appears right after refreshing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyAUE.png)

[milliseconds later, the CSS no longer does anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ0Uq.png)

The following code is the link to the css in my html file (have some other script tags in there as well):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home Page</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="js/bootstrap-icons.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="/PHP-Login-System/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
```

An image of directory tree (trying to link style.css with index.php):
[directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMCO0.png)

As far as I know, since **my styling does show up for a brief moment,** I don't think the error could be in my linking between the files, but I could be wrong. Any comments are appreciated.

Comment: could you try move style.css to folder assets/css/style.css and import it like <link href=“css/style.css” rel=“stylesheet” type=“txt/css”/>

Comment: @ttquang1063750 tried, but when I linked there nothing happened, and when I linked to /assets/css/style.css I continue to have the showing up briefly problem

Comment: Check your browser's developer tools to see if any files are missing or there are any errors.

Comment: @Brad There are 5 errors, but they all are 404 not found errors relating to the following: bootstrap.min.css (twice), bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap icons, and an unrelated script.js. Not sure, but I believe that this doesn't have any effect on styles.css?

Comment: check your javascript code, there might be a code to change your CSS properties. If you were able to see for a brief time, probably some javascript code changes the style, until it's executed you are able to see the old style

Comment: @Kuru I have looked through my js code and don't see anything that may change CSS properties. Please take a look https://github.com/huzai4a/PHP-Login-System and if the problem is identified, let me know. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good to me, I think the problem is coming from wamp server, because like you said, your css styles is showing up and disappearing.

My advice is:

1. Uninstall wamp total , download a fresh copy from the internet.
2. Restart your computer, then reinstall the new copy you downloaded

Comment: If I uninstall wamp, wouldnt that delete all my projects done through wamp? (some are in git repos some arent)

Comment: You should save your project files before uninstall WAMP